# "Although XX, it makes XXX" - unsure about logic in this sentence

Tags: syntax, prepositional-phrases

I am trying to say:

> Although by assuming XX
>   won't hurt us, in the sense that YY, it(XX) makes the proof of most
>   theorems become trivial and less interesting, and remove this
>   assumption (XX) will allow us to dig out more properties behind those
>   theorems.

I am not sure I use the right logic in "Although" sentence... I want to emphasize the second half of this sentence. Should I change the second "and" to "but"?

Also, if you see any other grammar error or wired usage of words, please comment out!

Thank you!

Comment: The entire clause *in the sense ... less interesting* is parenthetical (optional), so ignore that while checking the rest. The basic structure should then be clear - *Although A, B* (or *A, but B*), where A and B should be *statements*. For example, *Although living is dangerous, dying is even worse.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers So it is right to say: "Although XX still need more details, I think this is the right way to do it" ?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I once thought that "Although" can not pair with "but"

Comment: As I said, you can express advantage/disadvantage using either ***Although A, B*** or ***A, but B***. Choose one or the other "contrasting conjunction", but you can't use both at once. Also note that A and B are *statements*, which have to be grammatically correct in themselves. So your example *XX still need more details* is only valid if *XX* is a plural noun (such as *the workmen*). If *XX* is a singular noun (such as *the project*) the verb form must be ***needs***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delete *by*—*by* in this context casts *assuming XX* as the means through which a subject achieves some end. What you seem to mean is that it is the assumption itself which will not hurt us.
2. *It* in this context won't refer to *XX* but to *assuming XX*.
3. Delete *become*—that thought is already expressed in the verb *make* = "cause to become".
4. Change *remove* to *removing*—an 'unmarked' infinitive cannot act as a nominal.
5. As FumbleFingers says, you can use *although* or *but* to express a contrast, but not both. You could use *but* to set off the final clause in order to express a different contrast than the one expressed by *although*; but in this case the final clause is not a contrast with your argument in the first independent clause but a reinforcement of the argument from a different persepective. You could use an "on the one hand ... on the other hand" articulation, or set off the last clause with *while*. In any case, I'd point this with a semi-colon, to mark the change of perspective more strongly.

> Although assuming XX won't hurt us, in the sense that YY, it makes the proof of most theorems trivial and less interesting; and removing this assumption will allow us to dig out more properties behind those theorems.